# Ajax data not properly being sent to views.py (Django)

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Hello I'm quite new to django sorry. I'm trying to make a user object using the User class of django.contrib.auth.model I'm trying to use ajax to transfer the data from jQuery to views.py. For some reason, when I added the datatype: 'JSON' it stops executing the ajax and when I remove it the HttpResponse just gives me the entire html file. Not a single instance where a user was created.

**HTML**

```
<form action = "" method="post">

    {%  csrf_token %}
    <p class="label" id="l1"> Name: </p>
    <input type="text" class="textbox" id="name"><br>

    <p class="label" id="l2"> Username: </p>
    <input type="text" class="textbox" id="username"><br>

    <p class="label" id="l3"> Password: </p>
    <input type="password" class="textbox" id="password"><br>

    <p class="label" id="l4"> Confirm Password: </p>
    <input type="password" class="textbox" id="confirm"><br>

    <button id="signupbutton">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#signupbutton").click(function () {
var username = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var confirm = $("#confirm").val();
var name = $("#name").val();

errorval = errorCheck();
if (errorval == 0) {
    // transform data input to dictionary
    const infoset = {
        "name": name,
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    };
    console.log(infoset);

    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "create_user/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: JSON.stringify(infoset),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));

        },
        fail: function (data) {
            console.log("everything went to shit");
        }

    });
    $("#errormsg").text('creation successful');
}
```

**views.py**

```
def create_user(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse :
if request.method == 'POST':

    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    response_data = {}

    user = User(username=username, password=password)
    user.save()

    response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'
    response_data['userpk'] = user.pk
    response_data['username'] = user.username


    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response_data),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
else:
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from bartr import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name="admin"),
    url(r'^$', views.home, ),
    url(r'^home/', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^sign_up/', views.sign_up, name="sign_up"),
    url(r'^marketplace/', views.marketplace, name="marketplace"),
    url(r'^create_user/', views.create_user, name="create_user")


]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `JSON.stringfy`.

```
data: infoset,
```

Comment: that was the very first thing I've tried sadly it doesnt work as well.The same thing happens, the ajax doesnt fire but theres no errors in the console pls help

Comment: Did you try it without the `dataType` property as well?

Comment: Yes, it returns me the entire html when I print the data in success

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your urls; both in the patterns in urls.py, and in the URL you post your Ajax to.

You need to terminate all the patterns:

```
url(r'^home/$', views.home, name="home"),
url(r'^sign_up/$', views.sign_up, name="sign_up"),
url(r'^marketplace/$', views.marketplace, name="marketplace"),
url(r'^create_user/$', views.create_user, name="create_user")
```

and you need to post your Ajax to an absolute URL:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/create_user/",
    ...
});
```

Even better, you would use the `{% url %}` tag there; you can't do that in an external JS file though, so a better solution would be to give the form an action value and then use that in your JS:

```
<form action="{% url 'create_user' %}" id="create_user">
```

...

```
var url = $('#create_user').attr('action');
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    ...
});
```

(Also, it doesn't affect anything here but you definitely don't want to be using `const` in the declaration of `infoset`; it's not a constant at all.)

Comment: Hello! thank you for helping. I just wanted to ask what you meant by terminating the other urls. Sorry this is my first application in django and web development for that matter

Comment: I've shown you what i mean in the first code snippet.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that thank you so much! I'm gonna try this and see if it works

Comment: I tried your solution down to the last bit and unfortunately it gives me an internal server error

Answer (score 0):

First step to solve you problem indeed is fix your urls defintion, as mentioned Daniel Roseman in other answer.

Well, about your Jquery code

You don't need to set a dataType value and you don't need to use at all `JSON.stringify(infoset)`

To pass the data to your view you can use serialize method of Jquery, beacuse you have to pass also csrf token to your view (and for this reason you are getting your internal server error)

once you have fixed your urls definition, you can set your ajax as follow:

```
$.ajax{
    url: "/create_user/",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#your-form-id").serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    },
    fail: function (data) {
        console.log("everything went to shit");
    }
});
```

In your view you can use JsonResponse instead of return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response_data),
        content_type="application/json"
    )

You can do also as:

`return JsonResponse(response_data)`

I would like to recommend you this post where talking about ajax submition with Django, i found really helpful to me
[Django Ajax Form Submition](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Edit your view like this,

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    data = json.loads(request.POST)

    username = data.get('username')
    password = data.get('password')
    response_data = {}
    user = User(username=username, password=password)
    user.save()

    response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'
    response_data['userpk'] = user.pk
    response_data['username'] = user.username


    return JsonResponse(response_data)
else:
    return JsonResponse({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"})
```

Also remove JSON.parse from ajax request,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "create_user/",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(infoset),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("everything went to shit");
    }
```